# Try to find a sublist that doesnt occur in the range of ANY of the sublists in another list

Tags: python

```
enhancerlist=[[5,8],[10,11]]
TFlist=[[6,7],[24,56]]
```

I have two lists of lists. I am trying to isolate the sublists in my 'TFlist' that don't fit in the range of ANY of the sublists of enhancerlist (by range: TFlist sublist range fits inside of enhancerlist sublist range).
SO for example, TFlist[1] will not occur in the range of any sublists in enhancerlist (whereas TFlist [6,7] fits inside the range of [5,8]) , so I want this as output:

TF_notinrange=[24,56]

the problem with a nested for loop like this:

```
while TFlist:
   TF=TFlist.pop()
   for j in enhancerlist: 
       if ((TF[0]>= j[0]) and (TF[1]<= j[1])):
           continue
           
       else: 
           TF_notinrange.append(TF)
```

is that I get this as output:
[[24, 56], [3, 4]]

the if statement is checking one sublist in enhancerlist at a time and so will append TF even if, later on, there is a sublist it is in the range of.

Could I somehow do a while loop with the condition? although it seems like I still have the issue of a nested loop appending things incorrectly ?

Comment: The problem with your code is that you assume that if a given pair from `TFlist` doesn't overlap with a given pair `j` in `enhancerlist`, you're going ahead and adding that `TFlist` item which is an incorrect assumption. You have to check each `TFlist` against EVERY `enhancerlist` before you can conclude that a given `TFlist` item doesn't overlap.

Comment: You cannot edit your question to change the context after an answer has already been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative**

Use a list comprehension:

```
TF_notinrange = [tf for tf in TFlist 
                 if not any(istart <= tf[0] <= tf[1] <= iend 
                            for istart, iend in enhancerlist)]
print(TF_notinrange)
>>> TF_notinrange
```

**Explanation**

Take ranges of TFlist which are not contained in any ranges of enhancerlist

**Additional constraints**

Add additional constraints by creating a multiline conditional by either:

- Add backslash at end of line for line continuation

```
TF_notinrange = [tf for tf in TFlist 
                     if TFlist[0]==enhancerlist[0] and \
                         not any(istart <= tf[0] <= tf[1] <= iend)
                                for istart, iend in enhancerlist]
```

- Enclosing in parens which allows line continuation

```
tF_notinrange = [tf for tf in TFlist 
                 if (TFlist[0]==enhancerlist[0] and
                     not any(istart <= tf[0] <= tf[1] <= iend) 
                             for istart, iend in enhancerlist)]
```

**For Loop vs. List Comprehension**

As commented by doejohn list comprehension is for simple code.  For complex constraints, a for loop would be preferred due to readability.

```
tF_notinrange = []
for tf in TFlist:
    if (TFlist[0]==enhancerlist[0] and              # place multile constraints      
        not any(istart <= tf[0] <= tf[1] <= iend)):
        tF_notinrange.append(tf)
```

Comment: this is super helpful and seems to work. do you know how I could add a condition to your code? my ACTUAL lists each have a string in the first position that I want to check matches. do you know how I could get integrate this condition in:  " if TFlist[0]==enhancerlist[0]" . currently when I add it to the condition on the second line, it breaks your code ("if TFlist[0]==enhancerlist[0] and not any(istart <= tf[0] <= tf[1] <= iend")

Comment: thanks for your update!!! I appreciate you teaching me this syntax. I will use this type of for loop for the future too!) 

Comment: Just a note: most people would consider this code to be an anti-pattern. Comprehensions are for simple, short, succinct mapping/accumulation/filtering. As soon as a comprehension spills over into multiple lines, its readability drastically decreases. This code would not pass code review on most software development teams.

Comment: @ddejohn good point.  Added your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chained comparisons along with the less-common `for-else` block where the `else` clause triggers only if the `for` loop was not broken out of prematurely to achieve this:

```py
non_overlapping = []

for tf_a, tf_b in TFlist:
    for enhancer_a, enhancer_b in enhancerlist:
        if enhancer_a <= tf_a < tf_b <= enhancer_b:
            break
    else:
        non_overlapping.append([tf_a, tf_b])
```

Note that this assumes that all pairs are already sorted and that no pair comprises a range of length zero (e.g., `(2, 2)`).

EDIT: OP, you are making some mistake somewhere in your testing.

```py
In [1]: def non_overlapping(TFlist, enhancerlist):
   ...:     result = []
   ...:
   ...:     for tf_a, tf_b in TFlist:
   ...:         for enhancer_a, enhancer_b in enhancerlist:
   ...:             if enhancer_a <= tf_a < tf_b <= enhancer_b:
   ...:                 break
   ...:         else:
   ...:             result.append([tf_a, tf_b])
   ...:
   ...:     return result
   ...:

In [2]: enhancerlist=[[5,8],[10,15]]
   ...: TFlist=[[6,7],[11, 14], [54,56], [55,56]]

In [3]: non_overlapping(TFlist, enhancerlist)
Out[3]: [[54, 56], [55, 56]]  # [11, 14] is not present, as you claim
```

Comment: unfortunately this code doesnt work if we have a TF list like this : enhancerlist=[[5,8],[10,15]]
TFlist=[[6,7],[11, 14], [54,56], [55,56]]

Comment: What is your expected output in that case? According to your question as it is currently worded, this code *does* achieve your requirements.

Comment: this code outputs the following: [[11, 14],  [54, 56], [54, 56], [55, 56], [55, 56]] but the expected output shouldn't include [11,14]. it's ok though! I found the solution above

Comment: It doesn't. My solution also does not produce duplicates. You must have made some mistake. See my edit.